# No overload matches this call. in typescript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, overloading

I wrote the following component in React, I get an error.
Would appreciate help.

The main component:

```
export interface ICode {
code: (code: string) => void;
```

}
export default class UserCode extends React.Component{

```
state = {
    formFile: File,
    code: ""
}
//single
fileSelected(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    var file = e.target.files;
    console.log(file);
    if (e.target.files)
        this.setState(
            { formFile: e.target.files[0] }
        )
}
aaa() {
    let value = (document.getElementsByClassName("user-code")[0] as HTMLInputElement).innerText;
    alert(value);
    console.log(value);
    return value;

}
updateCodeInFather() {
    this.props.code(this.state.code);
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {/* <h6>Write your code here</h6> */}
            <Editor className="user-code"
                value={this.state.code}
                onChange={code => { this.setState({ code }); this.updateCodeInFather(); }}
                defaultLanguage="cpp"
                width={590}
                height={325}
                defaultValue={"void setup()\n{\n// put your setup code here, to run once:\n}\nvoid loop()\n{\n// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:\n}"}
            />
            <div>
                <input placeholder="browse" name="browse" id="browse" type="file" onChange={(e) => this.fileSelected(e)} accept=".txt, .ino" ></input>

            </div>

        </div>
    );
}
```

---

```
import Editor from './TagLanguage/Editor'
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    {
      <Editor></Editor>
    }
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The error appears:
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly): UserCode', gave the following error.
Property 'code' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ICode, context?: any): UserCode', gave the following error.
Property 'code' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly'.

Answer (score 0):

Need more clarity on how you want to use ICode.
If you want both the props and the state to have this interface, consider declaring Component this way:

```
export default class UserCode extends React.Component<ICode,ICode>
```

If you want only the props to have this interface:

```
 export default class UserCode extends React.Component<ICode,{}>
```